# Show all items in edit mode in RadGrid and save all changes by clicking on submit

Tags: asp.net, binding, view, radgrid, editmode

I need to realize a WebSite with a grid that shows all items of my Collection in edit mode like this:

[image: Grid]
On Apply the edited Collection should be saved.
On changing selection in the Supplier combobox shoud show the appropriated logo below.
(Is it possible to realise it using a binding instead of unbound code-behind implementation?)

How to implement it with RadGrid? Is any simplier as RadGrid solution in ASP.Net 4.0 with WebForms?

Comment: My problems with RadGrid are to show all items opened in edit mode and to update bounded collection to save the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Regarding the logo from down, try [a customised radcombobox showing tex with Icons](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/textwithicons/defaultcs.aspx)
2. I myself am looking for a way to configure and not code the update on 'Apply'